# Save object data in list and use in parameter

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need to use the object details of `obj` to save in a list or some sort to use as a parameter in my `send_order_verification()` function.

```
def order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form
            obj.save()

            send_order_verification(order_details, obj.email)
```

This is my `send_order_verification()` function:

```
def send_order_verification(order_details, email):
    return send_mail(
                    ('Thank you for your order #{0}', x),
                    ('Name: {0}\nEmail: {1}\nTelephone: {2}', x, y, z),
                     [settings.EMAIL_SEND_TO],
                     ['{0}' % email]
                     )
```

How could this be done? I tried with `order_details = [obj.name, obj.email, obj.telephone]` but can't access it with `order_details[0]` and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the object itself:

```
def order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form
            obj.save()

            send_order_verification(obj)

def send_order_verification(order_details):
    return send_mail(
                    ('Thank you for your order #{0}', order_details.name),
                    ('Name: {0}\nEmail: {1}\nTelephone: {2}', order_details.name, order_details.email, order_details.telefone),
                     [settings.EMAIL_SEND_TO],
                     ['{0}' % order_details.email]
                     )
```